# Grouping data by whether or not the data's feature intersects

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-structures, group-by

Suppose we have a table:

```
id  | aliases
-------------
0   | ['a0', 'a1', 'a4', 'a11']
1   | ['a3', 'a5']
2   | ['a16', 'a18']
3   | ['a6', 'a8', 'a10']
4   | ['a7', 'a8', 'a9']
5   | ['a3', 'a12', 'a14']
6   | ['a5', 'a16', 'a17']
```

and I'd like to group all `id`'s together that map to the same `aliases`; in other words, the end result groups together all `id`'s that have `aliases` that intersect, applied recursively. In the above case, we would have:

- `0` maps to `['a0', 'a1', 'a4', 'a11']`
- `1`, `2`, `5`, and `6` map to `['a3', 'a5', 'a12', 'a14', 'a16', 'a17', 'a18']`
- `3` and `4` map to `['a6', 'a7', 'a8', 'a9', 'a10']`

Is there an efficient way to do this? In my actual use case I have around 15M rows.

There is a naïve approach of streaming the rows and checking if each element of `aliases` in each new row is in the `aliases` processed so far; if so, collecting the `id`'s together of all rows with matching `aliases`, and mapping them to the union of the `aliases` matched.

However, this approach seems computationally impractical.

Comment: This make no sense to me, what rule are you mapping `id` and `list` together? any time that it and another id has something in common and also recursively?

Comment: If your lists are not long I don't see why this is impractical. But it is hard to tell not having a sample of your data.

Comment: @RockyLi yes that's it, sorry, I'll edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: I also didn't understand the question well. Do you want to create unique ID for common aliases? I think LSH algorithm helps.

Answer (score 0):

To run a `O(n*len(groupcount)` complexity code on this table shouldn't be that hard, just off the top of my mind:

Assume you have `id` as a list of id and `aliases` as list of lists, you can do:

```
bins = []
sets = []
for i in id: # Assume from (0 - n)
    alias = aliases[i]
    in_set = False
    for j in range(len(sets)):
        if len(sets[j].intersection(set(alias))) > 0:
            sets[j].update(set(alias)) # add alias to set, if any difference
            in_set = True
            bins[j].append(i) # append id to bins
            break
    if not in_set:
        bins.append([i])
        sets.append(set(alias))
```

`bins` will contain the `id` groups, and corresponding element in `sets` will contain the `alias` groups, you can use `list()` to convert these sets back to `list`. And since all set operations are hash based this ensure your program runs in `O(n*groupcount)` time.